# vba Direct copy for buttons

Tags: vba, excel

I know that I could do something like..

```
range("C1:D1").copy destination:=range("C2:D2")
```

for ranges, I would like to know if I can do the same for form control buttons

Current code below copies the button if found and then adds the button to the cell where the "hash tag" was written. In this example "#Button Back To Summary#". This all works fine but I would like to change the code to not go via the clipboard, for example like the above code for a range but for a form button.

> Calling Code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Cells.Find(What:="#Button Back To Summary#", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext _
        , MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    addshapetocell ActiveCell, "BK_TO_SUMMARY"
End 

DoEvents
On Error GoTo 0
```

> addshapetocell()

```
Sub addshapetocell(p As Range, btn_Name As String)
Dim clLeft As Double
Dim clTop As Double
Dim cl As Range
Dim r As Integer, R1 As Integer
On Error GoTo 0

R1 = 0
r = 0
Set cl = Range(p.Address)
clLeft = cl.Left
clTop = cl.Top
cl.value = ""

retryer:
update_Working_Status
Application.CutCopyMode = False
DoEvents

If r > 5000 Or R1 > 700 Then
    MsgBox "Code has attempted to copy a button 5000 times and has failed each time"
    Stop
End If

Worksheets("Odds").Shapes(btn_Name).Copy
DoEvents

If Application.ClipboardFormats(1) = 0 Then
    R1 = R1 + 1
    Sleep (50)
    GoTo retryer
End If

With ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    .Paste

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        r = r + 1
        Sleep (50)
        GoTo retryer
    ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Stop 'unhandled error has happend
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    .Shapes(btn_Name).Left = clLeft
    .Shapes(btn_Name).Top = clTop
End With
End Sub
```

Edit: update_Working_Status updates the status bar with "Working." & "Working.." etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to directly copy the Shape from one Worksheet to another without using the Clipboard. There is a `.Duplicate` method but I'm not aware of a way to change the Shapes Parent ie. which Worksheet it belongs to.

Have you considered programmatically re-creating the Shape using your template Shape as a base? This would be, effectively, copying the Shape but with a bit more effort involved. I've written the following as an example of how you could do this which, hopefully, you can adapt to your exact needs.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' Worksheet Receiving the Template Shape ie. the ActiveSheet.
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim newShape As Shape

Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Range("B10") ' Destination Cell.

' Worksheet containing the Template Shape.
Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet
Dim shapeToCopy As Shape

Set wsTemplate = wb.Sheets("Template") ' The Worksheet containing template button.
Set shapeToCopy = wsTemplate.shapes("#example") ' The name of template button.

' Different 'Shapes' are created via different Methods, so check the types that you want
' to support and implement the Method as appropriate.
Select Case shapeToCopy.Type

    Case MsoShapeType.msoFormControl
        ' Create the 'new' Shape based on the type and  size of the template, and the location of the receiving Cell.
        Set newShape = ws.shapes.AddFormControl(shapeToCopy.FormControlType, rng.Left, rng.Top, shapeToCopy.Width, shapeToCopy.Height)
        newShape.OLEFormat.Object.Text = shapeToCopy.OLEFormat.Object.Text ' Copy the template buttons caption.

    Case Else
        ' Unsupported Shape Type
        Exit Sub
End Select

' Now "Copy" the remaining shared Shape properties that we want to retain from the template.
newShape.Name = shapeToCopy.Name
newShape.AlternativeText = shapeToCopy.AlternativeText
newShape.OnAction = shapeToCopy.OnAction ' The name of the routine to run on button click
' etc...
' etc...
```

Comment: Hmm, That could work, rather than coping the button itself create a new button and copy the parameters of the original button. Thanks for the idea I will give it a try. I assume newShape.OnAction = shapeToCopy.OnAction will give the same code to the new button as the master button?

Comment: Yes, `OnAction` contains the name of the VBA function/routine that is run when it is clicked eg. Module1.mySub. Copying this means your new button will run the same code as your template.

Comment: @andshrew You beat me to it - This is what I was going to suggest as well

Comment: I have implemented this I am just waiting on users to use the functionality to see if it works in the real world :)

Answer (score 0):

In sheet1 I have an invisible activeX control (Oleobject): commandbutton1 
It can be placed alongside the 'hash tag' cell, using:

```
Sub M_snb()
  With Cells.Find("hash tag").Offset(, 1)
    Sheet1.CommandButton1.Top = .Top
    Sheet1.CommandButton1.Left = .Left
    Sheet1.CommandButton1.Visible = True
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This would only work if I had the buttons on each sheet where they may be used? currently 85 sheets, with the possibility of about 10-15 buttons per sheet and the user must be able to make the sheet (design and settings wise) if new sheets are required.